# Execute another powershell script with arguments for Icinga2 Monitoring

Tags: powershell

I have powershell script as below. If I run as below it works
test1.ps1 check_host 10.0.6.104 check_port 1433

```
param (
           $check_host=$args[0],
           $check_port=$args[1]
)

#$check_host="10.0.6.104"
#$check_port="1433"

# Icinga Exit Codes
#0 = OK
#1 = Warning
#2 = Critical
#3 = Unknown

$t = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient

$t.Connect($check_host,$check_port)
    if($t.Connected)
    {
        "Connection to $check_host via $check_port is OK"
        $returncode=0
        $t.Close()
    }
    else
    {

        "Cannot connect to $check_host via $check_port !"
        $returncode=2
    }

exit ($returncode)
```

but run for icinga format didn't work

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&'C:\Program Files\ICINGA2\sbin\test1.ps1 check_host 10.0.6.104 check_port 1433'" ;exit $LastExitCode
```

Comment: Can you post what is the error you are getting or what is the outcome you are getting? Also remove the exit and lastexistcode and check what it is coming as stdout. 
Also, if you are referring [THIS](https://community.icinga.com/t/windows-powershell-checks-with-icinga2/712), then make sure you do the configuration changes porperly

Comment: PowerShell parameter names should be prefixed with `-` by the caller: `check_host 10.0.6.104 check_port 1433` -> `-check_host 10.0.6.104 -check_port 1433`

Comment: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&'C:\Users\MammadovBQadm\Desktop\scripts\test1.ps1 -check_host 10.0.6.104 -check_port 1433'"

Comment: Error:
& : The term 'C:\Users\MammadovBQadm\Desktop\scripts\test1.ps1 -check_host 10.0.6.104 -check_port 1433' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &'C:\Users\MammadovBQadm\Desktop\scripts\test1.ps1 -check_host 10.0.6.104 -check

Comment: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Mammad...check_port 1433:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your script aren't important to this question; the question is how to execute a powershell script with arguments.  You can do that like so:

```
powershell -File "%ProgramFiles%\ICINGA2\sbin\test1.ps1" -check_host 10.0.6.104 -check_port 1433
```

The documentation for `powershell.exe` covers this case:

```
powershell -?

-File
    Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
    functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
    current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
    File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
    typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
    as the script file path followed by the script parameters.
```